# How to override host http header in azure app service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

It seems that azure app services do some reverse proxying by itself. So it is hard to place a custom proxy in front of the app service. Overriding the host header inside the proxy instance like

```
proxy_set_header Host $host
```

results in 403 forbidden error.

Is there a way to overcome this mechanism?

Unset the host header overriding

Comment: rore - have you figured out how to do this yet? We have the exact same need.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the CDN service to enable custom headers:

- Go to your web app
- select networking and select Inbound networking features
- choose Azure CDN
- create a new profile, or choose an existing one
  [image]
- select rules app and create your own rules
  [image]

Comment: I just tried this. I don't think the rules engine allows you to change the 'Host' header value.